# Why does Spatialite layer prompt for CRS if SRID was not explicitly defined in Layer Options?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, spatialite

In QGIS, if I `Save As...` a SpatiaLite file and don't enter an `SRID` in Layer Options, I will be prompted for a CRS upon opening the file. Yet [GDAL documentation](http://gdal.org/drv_sqlite.html) says that this option is only for forcing a different CRS/SRID, and the driver should normally be able to pick up the CRS and set it automatically. Is this expected behavior for QGIS, or is this a bug that should be reported?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS expects the CRS to either be defined within the dataset or by the user. If it doesn't have this information, it won't know what CRS to render the dataset in as the coordinates within the dataset itself could be rendered using any CRS.

Comment: Right, my question is _why_ it doesn't have this information. QGIS has that info when creating the layer, SpatiaLite has the capability to store it, but unless I use the SRID field, the CRS isn't stored. According to the GDAL documentation, Spatialite should be able to figure out what CRS to use on its own.

Comment: It's likely just a bug, when propmted to select the CRS, press cancel and it will still render

Comment: I think you have indeed hit on a bug. When you export a layer to Spatialite it gets SRID=0 (the default), instead of the correct SRID of the layer. Then QGIS, seeing no CRS in the Metadata, prompts each time.  I suggest you report this problem to QGIS developers.

Comment: I just hit the same issue, is it reported on qgis hub yet?